Isn’t the root progression or chord progression of a song meant to anchor in a foundation for rest of the instruments to experiment over?
What I mean is, isn’t the idea of creating and using a root progression or chord progression for it to be the foundation for a composition. With pop music (rap, r&b, latin, pop rock, country) the progressions are typically very simple switching between maybe two to four different progressions per song. Classical on the other hand, the progressions may switch a lot more.
But anyways, isn’t the typical idea to use an accompanying instrument to set the foundation for the composition so the singer, lead guitarist, etc can noodle over it and create their different parts while staying in key and in rhythm. Especially with a solo singer for example, playing chords on a guitar or keyboard and experimenting with different melodies until writing something you like.
And lastly, what I mean with root progressions or chord progressions is aren’t they practically the same thing, because, if you have a 4 chord progression, say Am C E G, wouldn’t playing just A C E G and not the full chord still do the same job as setting a foundation?
As if it were something like two voice counterpoint, or figured bass.
When I listen to music, I can always hear the progression of the roots, as if the roots are the anchor and the rest of the voices, including the rest of the notes in the chords, are simply an extension of the root notes. And it makes me think of the harmonic series, because if the current root note that is ringing out is on a C whatever other notes are being played will be most in tune based on the harmonic series (C, C, G, F, E). And thats the C sus 4 chord or C major.
There is an excerpt from the book Jazz Composition and Orchestration by William Russo. He says:

“Why is it so important to know the root of the chord? Because the roots of the chords will sound whether we want them to or not, whether or not the alphabetical symbol is correct. The root progression which emerges may not coincide with what we think we have written; it may be better or it may be worse; but art does not permit chance. The root progression supports the work. The total root progression is heard as a substantive element, almost like another melody, and it determines the tonal basis of the music. And the tonal basis of a piece is very important to the construction of themes and to the orchestration.”


Is there something that led you to doubt what you're saying? There are a few misconceptions in here, but generally saying a lot of stuff that's true and tacking on "…right?" isn't going to lead to very interesting answers. We can help a lot more if we know why you're asking.

@the-baby-is-you i’m asking to make sure my understanding is correct but also to make sure i’m not missing any important factors here, especially on the last paragraph. I guess I did ask multiple things but i’m generally just looking for an answer to the first question and want to know if the other stuff I asked is valid or a stretch.

Not sure what you're really asking here, but if your question is something near to "are chord progressions the base for their melodies", then the opposite question may be valid too, leading to a simple answer: they may, but they don't need to. As much as the same progressions may result in many melodies, the same melody could be harmonized with lots of different progressions. Whether you choose to start with one, or the other, or use a mix of those approach, is irrelevant.

I've written solos where the bassline stays the same but the harmonies on top get changed. You can easily end up with somewhere in between (your proposed harmony-first and the fairly common melody-first).

That Ab is far nearer Bb, using C as the root.

@musicamante I was thinking that it can’t be the opposite, but rather, no matter where you begin there is an inherent root progression that will be the tonal basis. That even if we begin with a melody, there will be an inherent root note “melody” based on where the stronger notes in the melody are. It’s slightly hard for me to explain it in words, thats why I asked the question to try to verify.

@Tim I actually just grabbed that from a random source because I forgot the order, but according to wiki its C G F E

@Dekkadeci Yes but wouldn’t those notes be slaves to the root progression? Also, not necessarily the bassline but the strongest notes in the harmony.

@Lestat "even if we begin with a melody, there will be an inherent root note “melody” based on where the stronger notes in the melody are" That depends: an "average melody" may lead to a chord or root progression (especially near the beginning and ending of phrases), but there are many occurrences of melodies that don't even have a clear or absolute tonal center, leading to many more possibilities of progression. What you believe the only inherent root note is just based on your music education and listening habit/taste, and while there are obviously progressions that make "more sense" »

@Lestat » depending on the notes on the melody, there never is an absolute answer. Interestingly enough, if we follow generic/common rules to create the most "logical" root/chord progression, we may even end up with something that may be quite boring. Or the other way around. Consider the case of Boléro: the melodies (the two themes) are relatively complex and would conceptually demand for some level of progression, still, almost the whole composition only uses one chord, with the bass line constantly repeated throughout the ending.

Supporting musicamente's point, reharmonization of melodies is fairly common, especially within the same piece. An extreme example across several pieces is the many harmonizations of repeated-note melodies - some are treated as ^1 (e.g. "Mars" from The Planets), others are treated as ^5 (e.g. "La Follia d'Amore" from Kirby Star Allies), and yet more are harmonized with descending chords (e.g. Felix Mendelssohn's Song Without Words in E Minor, Op. 62, No. 3).

@Lestat - Regarding your "Yes but wouldn’t those notes be slaves to the root progression?", the same-bassline harmonies tend to be different enough to not completely be slaves. I once harmonized an A-G-F-E bassline as Am-G-F-E and Am-Em/G-Dm7/F-C/E in the same piece.

"I was thinking that it can’t be the opposite": historically, it certainly was the opposite.  Melodies existed for thousands of years before chord progressions.  "even if we begin with a melody, there will be an inherent root note “melody” based on where the stronger notes in the melody are": look at some of Bach's different harmonizations of the same chorale tunes.  Yes, they are mostly in the same key relative to the melody, but the intermediate cadences aren't always, and the progressions in the middles of phrases are sometimes very different.

@Dekkadeci "I've written solos where the bassline stays the same but the harmonies on top get changed" this is probably more frequently true than not of baroque pieces using a ground bass -- passacaglias, chaconnes, etc.  People sometimes talk about "the Pachelbel canon chord progression" but it changes a couple of times; there are at least three if I recall correctly.

@Lestat Another typical example: "One Note Samba". Despite the name (and the "bridge" in the middle), it actually uses 2 notes in its main refrain: the fifth and first degree of the song key. Still, the main aspect and recognizability of the song is the relation of those single two notes and how they were harmonized. Based on your "it can't be the opposite", there should be only few "acceptable" progressions for those notes. Interestingly enough, except for the very ending, the tonic chord (which could theoretically be used for both notes) actually exists only in one place: during a rest.

@Lestat As a composition homework, I was recently asked to write the bass line of some known Bach chorales, only based on their melodies. In my first attempt, I ended up with three examples for the same melody, some of which quite different, including intermediate phrase cadences that ended up at different degrees or even harmonic context. During the following lesson, we found out further possibilities. While a chord progression may, to some extent, limit the possible melody, the opposite may give even much more liberty. Both may be a possible reference, or just one anchor of many.

You posted a lot of statements rather than questions. Here is one comment and one answer:

Classical on the other hand, the progressions may switch a lot more.

Some. But, a lot doesn't use much beyond I, ii, IV, V and vi along with transposition.

...root progressions or chord progressions is aren’t they practically the same thing..?

Mostly the same. But if you really indicate roots only it will leave out possible sevenths or other chord extensions, inversions, and possible mode mixing.
Think of a songs like Life on Mars or My Funny Valentine where the roots alone will miss the very, very important descending bass lines.
The important thing is to understand the difference between chord roots and a bass line/part. They aren't necessarily the same thing. And as a bass part becomes more melodic it tends to get away from playing just chord roots.

Yes, if you had to use just one thing as the harmonic foundation, it would probably be the bass line.  But just C in the bass doesn't tell us whether it's C major or C minor (or C7, Cm7, Cm7b5, C9(#11), D/C...  etc. etc.)
I'm not sure what your actual question is, though?   Everything you say is true, in its way.  None of it is the Answer To Everything.
And there's a heck of a lot of music which ISN'T about improvisation.  A lot is meticulously composed and notated, and our job is to play it as accurately and beautifully as possible, not to mess with the notes!
